# adonisjs Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed

Tags: node.js, adonis.js

I'm using relationships and I get this error everywhere

> Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed

well as I should. I’m using

```
.unsigned().references(‘id’).inTable(‘users’)
```

on many tables but getting error from everywhere

example usage

```
this.create(‘sub_users’, (table) => {
table.increments()
table.integer(‘user_id’).unsigned().references(‘id’).inTable(‘users’)
table.string(‘username’, 80).notNullable().unique()
table.string(‘password’, 60).notNullable()
table.string(‘name’, 160)
table.integer(‘state’).defaultTo(0)
table.timestamps()
})
```

Comment: Side note : Also posted on AdonisJs forum - https://forum.adonisjs.com/t/foreign-key-constraint-is-incorrectly-formed/490/5